# How to limit entity and/or field translation permissions to selected languages only?

Tags: 7, users, entities, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to give some user/role the permission to translate only one language?

I've seen these permissions:

- `Translate any entity`.
- `Translate field content for any fieldable entity`.

But these permissions allow users to translate all languages.

I have one user that has to translate to English and another user who translates to German ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting (valid!) question. But to my knowledge, and assuming this is for D7 (not D8), this is NOT possible ... yet.

Refer to (active) [issue # 1829630](https://www.drupal.org/node/1829630) for more details, which also references (fixed) [issue # 1807776](https://www.drupal.org/node/1807776) related to D8 (and contains a lot of interesting details ...).